# pass image uploaded from user gallery to another activity

Tags: android, image, gallery

i have a registration activity in which user can upload image from his gallery, i want to pass this photo to navigation drawer in main activity & also to userprofile activity and i cant find the way how, code for RegistrationActivity:

code for RegistrationActivity:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView uplo;
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
Context ctx = this;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    final Button bRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);
    //upload profile image
    uplo = (de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView)       findViewById(R.id.uploadimage);
    uplo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });



    bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
              i.putExtra("picture", String.valueOf(uplo));
                startActivity(i);
                finish();


        }

    });

}
//to take the chosen image from user mobile gallery
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        uplo.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));


    }


}
```

a sample of code would be very helpful 
thank you

Comment: you can save the path of image in preference and load the image using the image path from preference in different screens.

Comment: Step #1: Use an image-loading library (Picasso, Glide, etc.) that has a memory cache. Step #2: Pass the `Uri` identifying the image to the other activities, and they can load it using the same image-loading library and get it from the cache.

Comment: save your image path in shared preference and if the path available than show image

Answer (score 0):

Send the intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this, Upload.class);
intent.putExtra("picture", thumbnail);
```

and receive in other other activity

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("picture");
```

hope it work :)

Comment: This is incredibly wasteful of memory. Not only are you creating multiple copies of the `Bitmap` in your own process, but since `Intent` objects like this are cached by the system, you are also tying up additional system RAM needlessly. Also, if the image is too large, you will get a `FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION`, because there is a size limit on the `Intent` and its extras.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to send the image, just send the path.**
change it to.

```
bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
          i.putExtra("picture", picturePath);// send path
            startActivity(i);
            finish();


    }

});
```

and receive the path in another activity.

and set as..

```
.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
```

**2nd If you want to access picture on other activities**

Just put the path in shared preferences as `USER_DP` string. and get it whenever you want. **eg.**

```
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

    shared.edit().putString("USER_DP",picturePath).commit();// like this
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to save your path in to shared preferences and you can fetch it as per your requirement. initialise shared preference

`SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
          SharedPreferences.Editor  editor = sharedPref.edit();`

save path

`public void savePath(String key,String path){
       editor.putString(key, path);
        editor.commit();
   }`

retrieve path in your specific class--

`  public String getPath(String key ){

if (sharedPref.contains(key)){

```
String path="";
  path=sharedPref.getString(key, " ");
 return path;
```

}
return "";
 } `